# git GUI ignores .gitignore file?

Tags: git

I am creating my first `.gitignore` file. It looks like this:

```
/3212703ED955F10C7534BE8497B221F4/tester/history/*
/3212703ED955F10C7534BE8497B221F4/tester/logs/*
/3212703ED955F10C7534BE8497B221F4/history/**
*.hst
*.fxt
/3212703ED955F10C7534BE8497B221F4/MQL4/Logs/*
/3212703ED955F10C7534BE8497B221F4/logs/*

/*.Rhistory
/*.RData
```

However when I open the GIT gui and click "Stage Changed" I get a bunch of `.hst` files staged. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any git GUI not more than interface over primitive CLI commands.
It's possible that some of files you try to ignore are already tracking by git, so `.gitignore` doesn't apply to them. Try to remove them from git index:

```
git rm -r --cached . 
git add .
git commit -am "Drop ignored files"
```

Answer (score 2):

If the files were already stored in the repository then the ignore for will not ignore them. But it should ignore new files of that type.

Comment: When you say GIT gui, are you referring to the "original" [git-gui](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gui) that's bundled with Git, or another GUI?